# How to use external macro in function body?

Tags: c, macros

I'm writing a function that should have two versions: a debug version and non-debug version. Which one of the two functions is used should be decided by the caller.

I want something like this:

**caller.c**

```
// comment out the following line when not necessary anymore
#define MY_FUNC_DEBUG

#include "my_func.h"

// some code that calls my_func()
```

**my_func.h**

```
void my_func(void);
```

**my_func.c**

```
void my_func()
{
    // lots of code

#ifdef MY_FUNC_DEBUG
    // debug code
#endif

    // more code
}
```

This obviously won't work, because my_func.c is compiled separately from caller.c, therefore it can't know what macros it defined.

How can I make this work easily? I wouldn't want to write the two versions of `my_func` separately, because they share most of their code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using gcc, this problem can be easily solved by defining the macro at compile time via the `-D` option in both files.

In your example you could compile both files using `-D MY_FUNC_DEBUG` when you want the debug code to be activated and nothing otherwise. There is not need for defining `MY_FUNC_DEBUG` in caller.c.

Answer (score 0):

Make the debugging code in `my_func()` switchable at run-time.

#### my_func.h

```
#ifndef MY_FUNC_H_INCLUDED
#define MY_FUNC_H_INCLUDED

extern int my_func_debug(int level);
extern void my_func(void);

#endif
```

#### my_func.c

```
#include "my_func.h"

static int debug = 0;

int my_func_debug(int level)
{
    int rv = debug;
    debug = level;
    return rv;
}

void my_func(void)
{
    ...
#ifdef MY_FUNC_DEBUG
    if (debug)
        ...debug...
#endif
    ...
}
```

#### caller.c

```
void consumer(void)
{
    int old = my_func_debug(9);
    my_func();
    my_func_debug(old);
}
```

#### Discussion

The outline code means that you can have one copy of the source for `my_func.c`, but it can be compiled with debug included, or with it excluded.  The consumer code (`caller.c`) can request the level of debugging it wants, but whether that does anything useful depends on whether the copy of `my_func.o` (`my_func.obj` on Windows) was compiled with debug included.  You get one source file; you get to choose which variant of the object file is included in the program with `caller.o`.  And at runtime you can request debugging.

Note that `my_func_debug()` is unconditionally defined; it just doesn't do anything very useful if the `my_func.c` code is not compiled with `-DMY_FUNC_DEBUG`.